# Custom "Loading..." UIView

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, uiview, uialertview

I need to implement a "Loading..." alert view while doing some background processing in my app.

example:
[image]

I know I can create such view myself, but I was wondering if there's any drop-in I can use that support some cool animation and the likes, may save me some valuable time.

Thanks

Comment: i don't think there is any such built-in control present, you need to create your own :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I use and recommend MBProgressHUD.

https://github.com/jdg/MBProgressHUD

Comment: Looking good. Any way I can change the background color from black to Gray for example ?

Comment: It doesn't look like it supports different color themes at the moment.  It is open source, though, so perhaps it's worth modifying and contributing back to the project.

Comment: Thanks, that's what I did. Turns out it's quite easy to do so.

Answer (score 1):

The example is fairly trivial to implement. Create a `UIView`, round the corners (e.g. `view.layer.cornerRadius = 5;`), and plunk on a `UIActivityIndicator` and a bit of text. If you want "cool animation", then you'll have to work that out yourself, but the `UIActivityIndicator` will animate on command.

Comment: Yep, I know it's fairly easy to implement myself, thought there may be an open sourced custom alert view that already implements such animations. Thanks

Comment: @Idan So, you are looking to include a dim/opaque background as well?

Comment: Indeed, something that would allow me to change the background color/opacity and support some cool animation. Actually @Randall answer was quite good. Need the same thing just with the option to change the background color/image.

Answer (score 1):

Check out DSActivityView. It's an open source control that does this.
http://www.dejal.com/developer/dsactivityview

Comment: Looks good! even though I wish I could have change the background color.

Comment: you have the source code, so you can change it to whatever you want

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to create a custom view, you may like to know that there is a [UIActivityIndicatorView](http://developer.apple.com/library/IOs/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIActivityIndicatorView_Class/Reference/UIActivityIndicatorView.html).  That might be a good place to start.

Comment: Yep, I'm familiar with activity indicator, I think you got me wrong. Thanks though

Answer (score 0):

Best way to implement "Loading..." alert view is to, create your own custom UIView and add that view on top to the view you want to show or use DSActivityView mentioned in the last comment.